# project running from eclipse(Juno) Jboss but not from standalone Jboss 6 AS

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

To all Jboss experts!
I'm in the process of upgrading an old Java web project that used to run under Jboss4. I'm using eclipse/maven and jboss6 AS as dev tools.
Now here is my issue. I'm able to build and run the war file on the eclipse Jboss server. But when I'm running (copy and paste the file to the server deploy Dir) the same file on a standalone Jboss server the Ejb bean are not being installed and of course cannot get bound to the JNDI. 
Any reason why this is happening?
Am I missing any jar file that I should be added to the server Library?
Thanks

Comment: Can you include a copy of the error message that you're seeing?

Comment: I'm getting the following Exception NameNotFoundException: "local bean" not bound. Also I realized that I'm running a web project (war) that has EJBs classes, which is not really the best practice. But how come the eclipse server deploy those EJBs?